# Changing CAShapeLayer's path in for loop makes no effect

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, cashapelayer, cgpath

I'm changing **CAShapeLayer**'s path in `for` loop, but it only shows the last result of loop. I know, that I can do that with **CABasicAnimation** but I need to change path this way. Any ideas how to do that?

```
UIBezierPath *path = [ShapeManager getCirclePathAppendedWithCirclePathWithRadius:radius
                                                                        andFrame:self.view.bounds];
self.layer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd;
self.layer.fillColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
self.layer.opacity = 0.5;
self.layer.path = path.CGPath;
[self.view.layer addSublayer:self.layer];
for (int i = 1; i < 100; ++i) {
    path = [ShapeManager getCirclePathAppendedWithCirclePathWithRadius:self.view.bounds.size.width-i
                                                              andFrame:self.view.bounds];
    self.layer.path = path.CGPath;
}
```

helper methods

```
+ (UIBezierPath *)getCirclePathAppendedWithCirclePathWithRadius:(CGFloat)radius andFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    UIBezierPath *backgroundPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:frame];
    [backgroundPath appendPath:[self getCirclePathWithRadius:radius andFrame:frame]];
    return backgroundPath;
}

+ (UIBezierPath *)getCirclePathWithRadius:(CGFloat)radius andFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    CGRect rect = frame;
    UIBezierPath *circlePath;
    circlePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:(CGPoint){rect.size.width/2, rect.size.height/2} radius:radius startAngle:0 endAngle:M_PI*2 clockwise:YES];
    return circlePath;
}
```

Comment: What are you going to achieve with this for loop. It's not going to animate anything. If you set a variable million times, at the end you'll have just the last value, right? The same thing here

Comment: i'm trying to draw layout depending on a device position (using CoreMotion).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right about using CABasicAnimation.

1. Remove your `for` loop, it is not going to do the job.
2. Add `CABasicAnimation` for `path` key with values to interpolate between. This code should be called only once in `viewDidLoad` method:

```
UIBezierPath *fromPath = [self.class getCirclePathAppendedWithCirclePathWithRadius:self.view.bounds.size.width andFrame:self.view.bounds];
UIBezierPath *toPath = [self.class getCirclePathAppendedWithCirclePathWithRadius:self.view.bounds.size.width-99 andFrame:self.view.bounds];

CABasicAnimation * animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"path"];
animation.fromValue = (id)fromPath.CGPath;
animation.toValue = (id)toPath.CGPath;
animation.duration = 1; 

[layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"pathAnimation"];
layer.speed = 0;
```

**Update:**

3. In the last line you set `speed` value to 0 because you're going to set animation progress manually:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) double progress;

- (void) setProgress: (double) progress {
    _progress = progress;        
    layer.timeOffset = (CFTimeInterval)progress; 
}
```

This assumes that animation duration is 1.0. Otherwise you need to set

```
layer.timeOffset = (CFTimeInterval)(progress * totalDuration);
```

Now just set progress in motion callback according to the updated value.

Comment: i've tried this. But i need to draw ui depending on device position. I'm receiving device motion updates about with 0.01time interval, and i need to do animations very fast

Comment: So you want to update path according to motion value every time your callback is called (~60times per second)?

Comment: Yes, that's what i need

Comment: @passingnil Have you tried the solution with `timeOffset` and `layer.speed = 0`?

Comment: @passingnil Finally we did it :)